# Python Gae app not sending emails once deployed

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have this code for sending email.
it works well with localhost and in the logs i can confirm that an
email has been sent

Once i upload the application, the emails are no longer sent.

```
  message = mail.EmailMessage(sender="ISP leave request <noreply@xxxAPP-IDxx.appspotmail.com>",
      subject="NEW LEAVE REQUEST - REQUIRES ADMIN APPROVAL")
  message.to = 'xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com'
  message.body = """  YYYYY,
                      The below employee has requested for a leave.
                 Name: %s %s
                 leavetype: %s
                 Days.: %s
                 From : %s
                 To : %s
                 Reason: %s
                 Please reply.
                 """ %  (thisuser.firstname,
               thisuser.lastname,
               leavetype,
               days,
               datefrom,
               dateto,reason)

  message.send()
```

Kindly assist

Comment: What's in your app engine logs?

Comment: @AbuAshrafMasnun 'using the server with --enable_sendmail
INFO     2015-12-16 12:47:09,921 mail_stub.py:143] MailService.Send
  From: ISP leave request approval <noreply@xxxxxx.appspotmail.com>
  To: xxxxxxx@gmail.com
  Subject: LEAVE REQUEST APPROVAL - STATUS
  Body:
    Content-type: text/plain
    Data length: 361
'

Comment: Is this the log from production?

Comment: it is the log when i run my application on localhost

Comment: Check production logs. Your issue is on production, logs from localhost doesn't help much.

Comment: I have checked but there is no error message on the same

Comment: could it be due to dev_appserver.py --enable_sendmail=yes and if so how do i fix it? [https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver?hl=en#Python_Using_Mail]

Comment: You should probably indicate how this code is invoked. If there is nothing in the log and no message received how do you know you are even calling this code.  Place some logging here and see if you get anything. If not you can't be running this code.  Try some basic debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the sender's email is not correct. According to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/#Python_Sending_mail) it must be one of the following ones:

> 1. The Gmail or Google Apps Account of the user who is currently signed in
> 2. Any email address of the form anything@appname.appspotmail.com or anything@appalias.appspotmail.com
> 3. Any email address listed in the Cloud Platform Console under Email API Authorized Senders

Comment: @Lips emails from anything@appname.appspotmail.com gor to my spam box i dont know why

Comment: cause most likely a few people abused it, so it's automatically marked as spam.. just authorize a more personal email and you should be fine.. also mark it as not spam :)

Comment: Thanks @Lipis le me do so